# Parallel downloads of Maven artifacts

Tags: maven

When building a project with dependencies not yet available in the local repository, I noticed that Maven 3.3.3 first downloads the dependency POMs sequentially and then proceeds with downloading the dependency JARs with up to 5 threads in parallel.

What's the reason for not using parallel downloads for the POMs also?

Is there an option to configure the number of parallel downloads of either POMs or JARs?

Comment: Based on you wrote your build should fail: dependencies not yet available in the local repository...` ...

Comment: sure it does? or is downloading pom's just too fast to be recognizable that they run in parallel?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Why should my build fail? This is a standard use case. Clone sources of P via Git or whatever. P lists dependencies on A, B, C in its POM. P, A, B, C are not in my local repo. Running mvn install on P,  Maven starts loading the POMs of A,B,C, then A.jar, B.jar, C.jar and any transitive dependencies, and then proceeds to build P.

Comment: Ah sorry..misunderstanding on my site.

Comment: the fact that this is still a thing in 2019 speaks a lot about maven... for devs who work on it you should think how many human hours are wasted because of your laziness (let me go check if my jar downloads are finished)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [Maven 3.9.0](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html), this is finally possible. The interesting bit in the release notes is

> Choice of resolver collectors: a new BF collector (with parallel POM downloads) has been added along the existing DF one.

Everything is a bit hidden away, but [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-324) are clear directions:

Add `-Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf` to your maven invocation to switch from depth-first (DF) to breadth-first (BF) dependency collection. This means that POMs will also be downloaded in parallel.

It looks from that issue that it is planned to make this the default mode.

Comment: Can this be specified in `~/.m2/settings.xml` somewhere -- _once_?

Comment: Yes, or you can set it via environment variables. See this question for instructions for both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310179/how-do-i-define-maven-system-properties-in-settings-xml

Answer (score 9):

What about maven.artifact.threads config variable ?

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Comment: Testing it does not seem to change anything in maven 3.6.3 as far as I can tell.

Comment: `-Dmaven.artifact.threads=4` works for me in 3.8.1

Comment: `maven.artifact.threads` is for parallel JAR downloads while the OP asked about parallel POM downloads.

Comment: this is awesome! I set it to 30 and the console is filled up with information related to downloads! Crazy good :-) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts(jars) are downloaded in parallel by default however poms are not.

Starting mave 3.9.0, using -Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf, poms will be downloaded in parallel in 5 threads, if you want to download with more threads,
use -Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf -Dmaven.artifact.threads=10. In such case, both poms and artifacts will be downloaded in parallel.

You can share more feedback to below JIRA so we can convince Maven community to make bf as default.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-324