# How do I define maven system properties in settings.xml?

Tags: maven

I am following [advice from the mvn project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) to use multiple artifact threads for parallel artifact resolution. This command seems to give me the desired result.

`mvn -Dmaven.artifact.threads=10 dependency:resolve-plugins`

Will this settings.xml automatically set `maven.artifact.threads` on every call to mvn?

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>moreDependencyThreads</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>maven.artifact.threads</name>
                    <value>10</value>
                </property>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>moreDependencyThreads</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: System Properties can't be defined in `settings.xml`.

Comment: You know that by default already 5 threads used?

Comment: I did not. It seems that my question is answered. The defaults are OK and I cannot change system properties using settings.xml. Thank you for your help @khmarbaise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this property in your settings.xml file by changing it as follows:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>moreDependencyThreads</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <maven.artifact.threads>10</maven.artifact.threads>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>moreDependencyThreads</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Does that create a user property or set a system property? https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Properties

Comment: When I tried this, `mvn clean install -X` printed out `[DEBUG] properties used {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, env.XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.name=Mac OS X, ..., line.separator=
, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, maven.artifact.threads=10, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.8, ...}`, so it has set the desired property value.

Comment: When using Maven 3.2.5 and the `-X` option I don't see any output like `[DEBUG] properties used ...` :-(

Comment: No need for `activeProfiles` is there is `activeByDefault` is true.

Answer (score 1):

As it also specified in tutorial, you can make it permanent via:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.artifact.threads=10
```

If you call that it will be permanent for that session, if you add tis to your ~/.bash_profile it will be permanent for that user. Now on every call maven will work with these options.

Comment: Is it possible to define these options in settings.xml instead of in environment variables?

Comment: You can make the reverse of what you want but I am not sure about your request. Why you want to do that?

Comment: If I define this in settings.xml I can create a recommended settings.xml file for my team. It can define our best practices. Adding or setting environment variables is acceptable but not as portable.